# how to login api using curl

Tags: php, curl

I want to auto login when hit the url . I am using curl php. When direct logged in on API than its response like

```
{"metadata":{"total_pages":1,"total_records":1},"data":{"token":"XXXXXXXX","time":"2017-04-10 05:42:14","user_id":XXXX,"site_address":"https:\/\/xxxxxxx.com","user_role":"admin","access":"member"}}
```

I also do this same using crul php get response array same as above. token is generated but am not loggedin .
my curl code is:-

```
   <?php
    $uname='XXXX';
    $pwd='XXXXX';
    $url_post='https://api.example.com/v3/public/loginGrant?site_address=example2.com&username=XXXXXXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXXX';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$uname:$pwd");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$arr=json_decode($result);
$arr= (array) $arr;
print_r($arr);
curl_close($ch);    
    ?>
```

When i print array than its returns array like

```
{"metadata":{"total_pages":1,"total_records":1},"data":{"token":"XXXXXX","time":"2017-04-10 06:32:54","user_id":XXXX,"site_address":"https:\/\/xxxxxx.com","user_role":"admin","access":"member"}}
```

my code generate the response same as a API response but it can't logged in me. What can i do ?

Comment: does the api accept login using get parameters?

Comment: yes api accept .

Comment: how can i logged in @hassan

Comment: does there any errors? print your curl errors and see

Comment: No , its gives the response properly , like 
Array ( [metadata] => stdClass Object ( [total_pages] => 1 [total_records] => 1 ) [data] => stdClass Object ( [token] => XXXX [time] => 2017-04-10 07:29:40 [user_id] => XXXXX [site_address] => XXXXXXXXX.com [user_role] => admin [access] => member ) )

Comment: how to save token in cookies

Comment: decode your output using json_decode(), then set your cookies with your token

Comment: actullay i am new with curl , can you tell me how can i set cookies

Comment: take a look at user comments [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) , there a lot of examples, it's complicated to put an example here as long as you are dealing with an api needs credentials

Comment: @hassan, can you please tell me the right way , how to set cookies

Comment: I want to generate cookies file like user_XXXX and value in this file is token id like tkn.XXXXXXXX. I have tried this curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); but it cannot set cookies

Comment: @hassan , tell me the right way , i have tried it again and again but can't succeeded. how can I save cookies with token id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141407/discussion-between-ranjeet-singh-and-hassan).